# The difference between uint8 and double images when using imshow

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imshow, imread

The following code snippet results a `double` [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jfo5.png).

```
f = imread('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\2.tif');
h = double(f);
figure;
imshow(h);
```

whereas, this other code snippet results a `uint8` [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsUuX.png).

```
f = imread('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\2.tif');
figure;
imshow(f);
```

While displaying these two figures, the displayed results of these two images using `imshow` are different, but what is the reason behind this difference?

Comment: `uint`! *unsigned* integer (not `unit`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images of type `double` are assumed to have values between 0 and 1 and `uint8` images are assumed to have values between 0 and 255. Since your `double` data contains values between 0 and 255 (since you simply cast it as a `double` and don't perform any scaling), it will appear as mostly white since most values are greater than 1.

You can use the second input to `imshow` to indicate that you would like to ignore this assumption and automatically scale the display to the dynamic range of the data

```
imshow(h, [])
```

Or you can normalize the `double` version using `mat2gray` prior to displaying the image

```
h = mat2gray(h);
imshow(h)
```

Comment: the magical behavior of imshow is almost never a good thing in a non-interactive setting. you can save yourself surprise and pain by wrapping it in a function that checks assumptions about input type and range.